# Biblatex inproceedings sends year to end and prints note twice

Tags: biblatex

I am using [Curve CV template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv) to create a resume, and `settings` in the below MWE comes from there. There are two problems:

1. Using `@reference` sends year to the end, while I have the year in parentheses following authors in other reference styles, like article.
2. When `note` is used, it appears twice in the reference, (see `Accepted` as an example).

While the second one is not vital, the first one is a layout breaker. Any suggestions?

When I change `@conference` to `@inproceedings`, both problems get resolved. However, the reference then appears under `Journal Articles` section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{curve}

\PassOptionsToPackage{style=apa,sorting=ydnt,defernumbers=true, uniquelist=true}{biblatex}

\usepackage{settings}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url={\textsc{url}}}

\mynames{Doe\bibnamedelima John,
  Doe/John,
  Doe/\bibnamedelimi J.}

\leftheader{%
\centering
  \LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\Huge{John Doe}
  \medskip\small
  
  \makefield{\faEnvelope[regular]}{\href{mailto:abc@def.com}{\texttt{abc@def.com}}}
}

\rightheader{~}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%% JOURNAL PAPERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
@article{journalpaper,
  title={My Journal Paper},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={Top Journal},
  volume={1},
  pages={1--2},
  year={2025}
}
%%%%%%%%%%% WORK IN PROGRESS %%%%%%%%%%%%
@unpublished{wip,
  title={My Work In Progress},
  author={Doe, John and Roberts, Julia},
  note = {[In Progress]},
  year = {2027}
}
%%%%%%%%%%% CONFERENCE PAPERS %%%%%%%%%%%
@conference{conf,
  title={My Conference Paper},
  author={Doe, John and Roberts, Julia},
  year = {2026},
  booktitle = {A Conference Proceedings},
  note = {Accepted}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% PRESENTATIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%
@misc{present,
  title={A Nice Presentation It Was},
  author={Doe, John},
  year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubrichead{Research Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Journal Articles},type=article]

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Conference Proceedings (Full Papers)},type=inproceedings]

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={In Progress and Submitted Manuscripts},type=unpublished]

\makerubrichead{Conference Presentations}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading={none},type=misc]

\end{document}
```